# "Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand" when or-ing two ulongs

Tags: c#

The following C# code generates a warning:

```
var a = (ulong)5;
var b = a | (ulong)new int[10].Length;
```

> Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand; consider casting
>   to a smaller unsigned type first

What is the reasoning for this warning? It seems to me that both sides of the OR should have static type `ulong` and therefore no sign-extension should be happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point it's making is that `Length` returned an `int`<sup>*</sup>. You then forced a conversion to `ulong` which resulted in sign-extension (because, effectively, it first went via `long`).

If you had cast to `uint` before casting to `ulong`, the warning would disappear<sup>1</sup>.

```
var a = (ulong)5;
var b = a | (ulong)(uint)new int[10].Length;
```

This, in many ways boils down to the fact that the C# cast can do different things. Some don't change the data at all, just how the compiler acts on it, others require actual conversions. I *sometimes* yearn for modern C++'s `reinterpret_cast`, etc.

---

<sup>*</sup>Yes, we all know that `Length` will never return a negative number anyway, so sign extension here is a non-issue. However, there are multiple reasons why unsigned types, *in general*, should be consigned to the bin.

For instance, if you're doing bit manipulation, you generally care about the *bits* rather than how they might be interpreted as a number. `ulong` vs `long` often doesn't make sense here, since it's *not* a number, it's a bit field.

<sup>1</sup>I.e. what the warning already told you to do. First cast to the smaller unsigned type.